# Can you replace two different texts with this.queryText.replace?

Tags: javascript, parameters

I need to replace two texts depending on the same parameter. Is there any way to do this? 
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
 if(params["This_year"] == "1/1/14"){
    this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("/**year**/", "2014") 
    replace("/**Last_year**/, "1/1/13")}
```

I'm not exactly sure if that last line would actually work. Is there an alternate way of doing this?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the second line, it's not stored. It would be stored if you put a dot at the end of the first line `...).replace(...`

Comment: Should I just repeat this.queryText = this.queryText.replace, instead of just putting replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dot in between the two String.replace calls, on the same line, like so:

```
if(params["This_year"] == "1/1/14"){
    this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("/**year**/", "2014").replace("/**Last_year**/, "1/1/13"); }
```

The second call will modify the string returned by the first call.

My spider sense tells me that there's probably something about this that can be generalized into an algorithm, but without seeing more examples, it's hard to know what that would be.

Comment: Thanks. The rest of the small little JS query is just me adding 2015-2020 to the list. I have two parameters as of now, one for this year, and one for last year. That doesn't sit tight with the people that will be using this report, so I need to find a way to get rid of the last year parameter.

Comment: Oh and your reputation has now skyrocketed.